# How to disable TinyMCE from auto formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

If I write the follow,

```
<tr>
 <td>data1</td>
 <td>data1</td>
 <td>data1</td>
</tr>
```

↓

```
<p>data1data1data1</p>
```

It's like this because of tinymce auto formatting.
there isn't `<table>` tag.
In another case,if there is the block element in `<a>`, all `<a>` element is vanished.

my configure is the follow. (tinymce 4.2.5)

```
tinymce.init({
    language: "ja",
    plugins: ["code link"],
    selector: ".tiny-mce",
    valid_elements: "*[*]",
    body_id: "wrapper",
    toolbar: " bold underline | formatselect | link unlink | code",
    menubar: false,
    height: 500,
    block_formats: "Paragraph=p;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4;Heading 5=h5;Heading 6=h6",
    relative_urls : false,
    content_css : ["/css/styles.css", "/js/admin/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css"],
});
```

Can I disable this function?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you try paste your html code to `HTML Code` mode of TinyMCE?

Comment: Have you tried to remove block_formats from config ? also upgrade to latest TinyMCE, which has many bugfixes and some cool new stuff